# Question concerning a special Fredholm operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $C\subseteq H^\infty (D)$ the space of functions that are analytic in the unit disc $D:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\ |\ |z|<1\}$, and that have continuous continuation on $D \cup$ ∂$D$ and let $C$ be equipped with the maximum norm.

Let $g \in C$ with $g\neq 0$ on ∂$D$ and let $k$ count the zeroes of $g$ in $D$ with multiplicities.

Let $A : C\ni  f \mapsto gf ∈ C$ the operator, defined by left-multiplication by $g$.

> Question: Why is $A$ Fredholm and why is index $A=k$ ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you know that $A$ is Fredholm and that the index is $k$? -- Is this homework?

Comment: The index is $-k$. Proof: $A$ is injective by the identity theorem. Let $z_1, \ldots ,z_r$ be the zeroes of $g$, with multiplicities $m_1, \ldots ,m_r$. Let $L: C \to \mathbb{C}^{\sum_i m_i}$ be the linear map which sends $f$ to the first $m_i-1$ derivatives of $f$ at $z_i$ (for all $i$). $L$ is surjective, and the kernel are those analytic functions which are divisible by $g$. If $Lf =0$, then $f/g$ is analytic by Riemanns extension theorem, and bounded on the closed disc since $g$ is nonzero on $S^1$.